# Significance testing between two hyperbolic curves

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonlinear-regression

I have two curves for biological data (one-site binding). These curves were both fit using the following (Michaelis-Menten) model:

BRET2 = (Bmax * RFU_RLU)/(Kd + RFU_RLU)

Note: (x,y) here is represented by (RFU_RLU, BRET2), while Kd and Bmax are parameters estimated in the model.

[image]

I would like to know the appropriate test to determine if there a significant difference between the two curves. From a qualitative standpoint I would define a significant difference as sufficient vertical distance between the two curves.

Comment: Your model specification is incomplete: what did it assume about any differences between the data and the fitted curve?  And are those error bars around some the points in the graph?  If so, wouldn't they make it abundantly clear there are differences between the data at practically all levels of RFU_RLU--and therefore differences between the curves?

Comment: I'm not well versed in statistics, is this what you mean by assumptions?

1. The data is pretty sparse with 24 observations per curve and it tends to deviate a little from being normally distributed
2. The treatments are independent from one another
3. There is no auto-correlation
4. There is slight heteroscedasticity, particularily between treatments.

Lastly, yes those are error bars on each point and each point consists of two observations. In addition, I have a number of other curves (not pictured) that don't have as quite a large visual seperation.

Comment: For example, your curve doesn't explain how the data vary from the curve - a model is a model for the data. If we can condition on your x-axis variable (e.g. if the actual value and what you think it is will be the same that would be sufficient), a full statistical model would describe the distribution of the y-variable at each x-variable. If you could at least describe how the spread of points changes as the x-variable changes or describe the way in which the noise/error term comes into the measurement of the y-variable, that would be useful in writing down a model. ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... If you've been using unweighted nonlinear least squares then you've effectively been assuming additive error with constant variance on the y-variable (and no measurement error - or so little you can ignore it - on the x-variable -- the absence of error bars on the x suggests this may have been your explicit assumption). The presence of error bars (in the y-direction) on the points suggests they're not equally precise, which (if you assume additive errors would suggest a weighted model), and possibly a weighted nonlinear least squares model. ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... however if the error bars are just based on the deviation between the two points at each x-value, why not just display all 24 points? If you're interested in differences between the curves that would correspond to differences in either or both of the two parameters, but if you're primarily in vertical difference (which will often be largest at large x) then it may be that you're mostly interested in differences in Bmax rather than in Kd. Is that the case or are *any* kind of differences (including curves that cross again above x=0)  of interest?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have been using weighted nonlinear least squares to generate the curve (using the nls function in R). I chose to display 12 points because each curve consists of two experimental replicates (e.g. the same curve is made twice, each experiment generates 12 points). From a biological standpoint I'm interested in both differences in Bmax and Kd, but Bmax is arguably the more important of the two.